# extract names between two strings in excel

Tags: excel

I am new to VBA and want to separate names in columns of excel sheet. I have data in diff format.

```
<div class="ExternalClassFDA2438C2367434332FDC2B85CB2">Nic Dan</div><div class="ExternalClass7BC342797C18448A8401C18ACF0E8F3D">&#160;</div><div class="ExternalClassEETYG34BA32FA455B85CB2">Tom Han</div>
```

I want Nic Dan , Tom Han in one column. I tried spliting data based on > but it is not working. Any easy workaround for this task... I do not want to write VBA code.

Comment: Search on here, there are many examples using left() and find() etc You can look in the excel function list for text functions then combine some.

Comment: Turn your data into valid XML and use the `FilterXML()` worksheet function.

Comment: @Dominique beat me to the idea; `=FILTERXML("<root>" & B2 & "</root>", "/root/div")` (where `B2` is your data). You'll want to look up a solution to further narrow that down to omit blank cells in the resulting array.